# Making a list of references extracted from research paper and download them

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to make a list of references in a research paper. I have extracted from pdf and stored them all in a txt file. The problem is when i run the following code it dosent appear to be in the list, in console they are in one line only. I cant share the output because stackoverflow wont let me.! I need help storing them properly.
The code

the code for making a list:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("D:\\ref.txt"));
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (s.hasNext()){
    list.add(s.next());

}
System.out.println("LIST:" +list);
s.close();
```

tHE OUTPUT :

> LIST:[References, :, [1], J., Bailey,, C., Zhang,, D., Budgen,, M., Turner,, and, S., Charters,, “Search, engine, overlaps, :, Do, they, agree, or, disagree?”, in, Second, International, Workshop, on, Realising, Evidence-Based, Software, Engineering, (REBSE, '07), ,, 2007,, p., 2., [Online]., Available:, http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=42732, 74, [2], K., Yang, and, L., I., Meho,, “Citation, analysis:, A, comparison, of, google, scholar,, scopus,, and, web, of, science,”, in, 69th, Annual, Meeting, of, the, American, Society, for, Information, Science, and, Technology, ,, Austin, (US),, 2006,, pp., 3, –, 8., AND +10 references which iam not allowed to share

After I have completed the list, I need to run this list on google so that all the papers in the list are downloaded. I have the code to download but it only does for one paper. I want to download the full list I've just made.
The code:

```
try {
   //var a= doc.replace(" ","+");

    Document doc = Jsoup
            .connect("https://scholar.google.com.pk/scholar?hl the paper I want")
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36")
            .get();

    String title = doc.title();
    System.out.println("title : " + title);


    Elements links = doc.select("div.gs_ggsd").select("a[href]");
    //Element  = doc.select("div.gs_ggs gs_fl").first();

    for (Element link : links) {
        //System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
        URL website = new URL(link.attr("href"));
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\paper.pdf");
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
} 
       // System.out.println("text : " + link.text());
    }
```

Comment: Share the output. I'm betting that your list is fine.

Comment: Either that or simply iterate through the list: `for (String s : list) { System.out.println(s); }`

Comment: " I cant share the output because stackoverflow wont let me.! " I don't believe you. Edit your question.

Comment: why not use s.hasNextLine() and then list.add(s.nextLine()) to add line by line to your list

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Sir there are more than 2 links in it, and i dont have reputation of 10 in order to share that output.! I tried again but it gave me the same message

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Please have a look. !

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz: Please see the output after editing the question, by hasnextline() there is space after every comma.! Let me know wether Iam in list in the output I haveshared, or the one I am telling u rite now. ?, because i need the whole reference so that I can parse it onto google scholar to download that particular paper.

Comment: It's all in there, in the list. Do what @RAZ_Muh_Taz suggests, use `s.hasNextLine()` with `s.nextLine()`. instead of `hasNext()` with `next()`

Comment: [1], J., Bailey,, C., Zhang,, D., Budgen,, M., Turner,, and, S., Charters,, “Search, engine, overlaps, :, Do, they, agree, or, disagree?”, in, Second, International, Workshop, on, Realising, Evidence-Based, Software, Engineering, (REBSE, '07), ,, 2007,, p., 2., [Online]., Available:, http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=42732, 74                          I actually need this whole string, otherwise its of no use @HovercraftFullOfEels: Are u sure Sir that the ouput i shared is in a list???

Comment: Take a deep breath and calm down a bit. Everything is working as expected. Again, use hasNextLine and nextLine, again test it yourself by iterating through the list with a for-each loop as I suggest, printing each item in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try grabbing line by line instead.
Show us the output you get when trying the following code

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("D:\\ref.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (s.hasNextLine()){
        list.add(s.nextLine());
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(i + ":" +list.get(i));
    }

    s.close();
```

Comment: Sir the output is the same as i've shared above in "tHE OUTPUT" Can you please confirm that is properly stored in a list ?? Iam sorry due to this threshold, I cant share the full output .! @RAZ_Muh_Taz

Comment: this would store whatever each line of your text file contains. i don't know what the text file looks like. You could also split the input around a comma because it looks like your data is in CSV format.

Comment: The output is fine, I guess its in list, and iam ready to send it to google scholar to download all the available papersin the list. ! I have shared the code to download, but the problem is I dont know wot to change or add in order to parse a list and download all the papers in it.! Please have a look

Comment: go to the page that one of the google references is, look at the web address and see what part of the reference is in the web address. Show an example of what the web address is for reference [1] or something

Comment: TASK DONE ALREADY.! TY!